# Why do constructors need to be named exactly after the class?

Tags: c++

What is the reason a constructor needs to have the exact same name than the class? Is it purely a sintactic reason? Is it possible to define the constructor with a different name?

Comment: But how would you use such constructor?

Comment: How will you tell the compiler that some method is a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to have the same name as the class to tell it apart from other (non-special) member functions. This is a convention for the constructor (and destructor, when prefixed with a tilde) to unambiguously tell the compiler that you are creating a constructor for your class and not just a member function in the class.

Comment: But is it just a convention or is it a sintactic rule for c++?